# is System.in an object reference of InputStream class?

Tags: java, io, system.in

InputStream is an Abstract class.Then how are we able to access System.in.And moreover int read() is an abstract method in InputStream class.Then how are we able to access System.in.read() method if read() is an abstract method.
Like

```
int a=System.in.read();
System.out.println((char)a);
```

Comment: maybe have a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)...

Comment: You should check the initializeSystemClass() method in System class which contains the details of how these Streams are initialized.

Comment: I don't think that this is a bad question. One shouldn't down vote it.

Comment: It is an instance of `InputStream` and whatever concrete class the implementation provides. This is a common enough idiom that you shouldn't have to ask about it specifically for `System.in`.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to read more about abstraction and inheritance methods in Java.

If you extend an abstract class, you have to implement its abstract methods. This way, you provide an implementation for it, which can be called by consumers.

`System.in` is an instance of a class which extends `InputStream`, not of `InputStream` directly.

Answer (score 2):

> *is System.in an object reference of InputStream class?*

yes!, it is declared/documented in the System class:

```
/**
 * The "standard" input stream. This stream is already
 * open and ready to supply input data. Typically this stream
 * corresponds to keyboard input or another input source specified by
 * the host environment or user.
 */
public final static InputStream in = null;
```

but at runtime is a reference to a `BufferedInputStream` class

so ou are not instantiating an abstract class
[image]

Comment: In the implementation you looked at. There is nothing in the specification that guarantees that.

Comment: do you mean is platform dependent?

Comment: I didn't say a word about platforms. It is defined by the implementation, not by the specification.

Comment: hotspot? or another?

Comment: Stop trying to particularise a general statement. It isn't specified `=>` it can be anything that satisfies the contract.

Comment: Thanks.Cleared my doubt.

Comment: @SouravDeb I hope not, unless you're referring to my comments.

Answer (score 0):

`InputStream` is an `abstract` class which cannot be instantiated directly. `System.in` refers to the object of type `InputStream` which means that `System.in` refers to the object of that class which `extends` the `InputStream` class.

**For example**

```
abstract class IAmAbstract{
// ...
}

class IAmNotAbstract extends IAmAbstract{
// ...
}
```

Of course, the following statement is correct:

```
IAmNotAbstract obj = new IAmNotAbstract();
```

As well as this statement is also correct:

```
IAmAbstract obj = new IAmNotAbstract();
```

So, any object of `subclass` of `InputStream` is also a type of `InputStream` class and `subclass` itself.